# NativeScript Grid row height adjustment with animation

Tags: animation, nativescript, grid-layout

I have Grid Layout which has three rows and I am using javascript to adjust height on the press of the button.

Code behind (xml):

```
<GridLayout columns="*" id="grid-id" rows="300, 40, auto">
 ....
 ....

</GridLayout>
```

Javascript:

```
var newHeight = 520;
myView.getViewById("grid-id").rows= newHeight + ", 40, auto";
```

Is it possible to animate this changes in height?

Comment: Set the rows to `auto, auto, auto` and set the height on the child elements. Then you may use [tween.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105091/animating-height-property) to animate height on each element.

Comment: @Maka Did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: @Narendra No I have not yet. Thinking to do px by px in for loop. Not sure how is that going to look.